# How do I extract the blog posts like this site did?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, rss, ning

[This site](http://friendsorenemies.com) is built on Ning. You'll notice they have jQuery tabs set up on the home page and looking through the source code, you'll see that those tabs are getting their content from an outside url (below):

```
<div class="ui-tabs" id="tabs"> 
     <ul> 
          <li><a href="http://friendsorenemies.com/vip/blog/embedPromoted?pageSize=10">Features</a></li> 
          <li><a href="http://friendsorenemies.com/vip/blog/embedVip?pageSize=10">Vip Blogs</a></li> 
          <li><a href="http://friendsorenemies.com/vip/blog/embedAll?pageSize=10">All</a></li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

However, those urls aren't standard to Ning (I've tried appending */vip/blog/embedPromoted?pageSize=10* on a [similar Ning blog url](http://my.spill.com/profiles/blog/list) and it didn't work) which leads me to believe that they were created separately somehow to extract just the blog posts. Here is what a blog page on Ning looks like for reference: [link](http://www.friendsorenemies.com/profiles/blog/list?promoted=1)

Anybody have an idea of how they created these pages with just the blog posts? I originally thought of using the blog's [rss feed](http://www.friendsorenemies.com/profiles/blog/feed?promoted=1&xn_auth=no) but realized the rss doesn't include author avatars and certain post metadata information like how it is in the first link I posted above.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/vip` URLs on that Ning site is a custom feature from when Ning used to host custom PHP code. Since it's a custom feature, it's not available on other sites.

It's possible to create something similar using the [Ning API](http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/index.html) to aggregate blog content from a specific set of members into a single HTML page or RSS feed. It would have to be implemented on an external server.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Devin. Would you happen to be available for hire for something like this? Or know anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [rssinclude.com](http://www.rssinclude.com/), handy way to drop RSS feeds into a site.

If that won't work, you can use the [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) library to grab the HTML from the site jQuery style, but in PHP.

Comment: That was my first idea but then I realized that rss feeds don't include the author's avatar along with the post metadata (e.g. `Posted By Author | No Comments | May 6, 2011 | 5:25am`) So I think I need to search for another solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `rss feeds don't include the author's avatar` ? It is included in the [link](http://www.friendsorenemies.com/vip/blog/embedPromoted?pageSize=10) you have in your OP.

One way this could have been implemented is that they apply a XSLT temnplate to a RSS feed to build the HTML page .

Comment: Instead of the link in your post, [this](http://www.friendsorenemies.com/profiles/blog/feed?promoted=1&xn_auth=no) is actually the rss feed taken from the site. As you can see, there are no avatars included.